# Python String remove everything after specific character showed up 3 times

Tags: python, string, file

I have the following question.

I have a list full of file names and I want to filter out a specific part of it. Thing is, I won't be able to know the exact position of the information as it can change depending on the file itself. I can only be sure of the relative positions of the underscores.

What a example would look like:

```
'C:\\Path...\\SomeInfo_MoreInfo_123_456_789.PDF'
```

What would I have to do to only get the 123? My initial idea would be to remove everything before the third `_` and fourth `_` but I do not know how to accomplish that with `.split()`

Comment: `pathlib.Path(your_string).name.split('_')[-2]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make clear how `.split()` works, take a look at its output:

```
>>>a = 'C:\\Path...\\SomeInfo_MoreInfo_123_456_789.PDF'

>>>a.split('_')
['C:\\Path...\\SomeInfo', 'MoreInfo', '123', '456', '789.PDF']
```

Now, if the part of the string that you want is always after the first two '_', you can extract it doing:

```
>>>a.split('_')[2]

'123'
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
parts = a.split('_') ; ['C:\\Path...\\SomeInfo', 'MoreInfo', '123', '456', '789.PDF']
```

and finally:

```
result = parts[2] ; '123'
```

You must know that split return and array with the element separated by the value (_) you specified.

Answer (score 0):

```
string = 'C:\\Path...\\SomeInfo_MoreInfo_123_456_789.PDF'
new_list = string.split("_")
```

The `new_list` output would be:

```
['C:\\Path...\\SomeInfo', 'MoreInfo', '123', '456', '789.PDF']
```

and now we want to get the index of `123`:

```
target = new_list.index("123")
```

the out put would be:

```
2
```

and now we get the result:

```
result = new_list[target]
```

the output would be:

```
123
```

NOTE: with this method you can get any thing of string just replace `123` with your word

Of course we could do `new_list[2]` but what about if `123` path change?!